# Cross-Compile Kernel Module - error fixdep : no such file or directory

Tags: linux, makefile, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I am trying to cross-compile a TP-Link module for ARM920T of which the
details are following -

Module Source - `$HOME/Desktop/ashish/TL-WN725N_V2_150911/Driver/`
Toolchain Path - `/usr/local/3.4/arm-linux-uclibc/bin/arm-linux-uclibc-gcc`

I have exported path for my toolchain using -

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/3.4/arm-linux-uclibc/bin
```

I am running the following from the top level kernel source directory
(`$HOME/lhotse/products/p101/sw/branches/release4.X/kernel/linux-2.6.8.1`)
 of my target system

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-uclibc- M=/home/gauravmittal/Desktop/ashish/TL-WN725N_V2_150911/Driver/ modules
```

The command throwing the following error -

```
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
  CC [M]  /home/gauravmittal/Desktop/ashish/TL-WN725N_V2_150911/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.o
mv: cannot stat
`/home/gauravmittal/Desktop/ashish/TL-WN725N_V2_150911/Driver/core/.tmp_rtw_cmd.o':
No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [/home/gauravmittal/Desktop/ashish/TL-WN725N_V2_150911/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.o]
Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/gauravmittal/Desktop/ashish/TL-WN725N_V2_150911/Driver]
Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.24-23-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

When I do a just `make` on the top level driver directory, it successfully
creates a .ko file for me and I am able to install the module on my
workstion (running on kernel 2.6.24-23-generic), but couldn't find
where am I going wrong during cross-compiling the same.

Just that I am not able to understand how to move forward, as
relatively new to Embedded Development, any kind of help would be
appreciated.

**EDIT 2 :**

Started things from scratch again.

I have downloaded the linux source compatible to by target (linux-2.6.8.1) and have included the module source in `linux-2.6.8.1/drivers/net/wireless/tplink`

I have also copied the content of Kconfig from module source directory under wireless Kconfig to get it appearing in the make menuconfig menu. I did a make menuconfig and enabled the option for the same.

Now I did

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-uclibc- KSRC=/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.24.23-generic/ M=${PWD}/drivers/net/wireless/tplink/ modules
```

The output is as under -

```
CC [M]  /home/gauravmittal/Desktop/ashish/linux-2.6.8.1/drivers/net/wireless/tpwifi/core/rtw_cmd.o
fixdep: /home/gauravmittal/Desktop/ashish/linux-2.6.8.1/drivers/net/wireless/tpwifi/core/.rtw_cmd.o.d:
No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [/home/gauravmittal/Desktop/ashish/linux-2.6.8.1/drivers/net/wireless/tpwifi/core/rtw_cmd.o]
Error 2
make: *** [_module_/home/gauravmittal/Desktop/ashish/linux-2.6.8.1/drivers/net/wireless/tpwifi]
Error 2
```

I have tried searching a lot on the Internet but could not fix this. I am stuck at this from long..any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Take it you did run `make ARCH=... M=... clean` before cross compiling your module?

Comment: I however ran `make clean` before `make ARCH=... CROSS_COMPILE=... M=... modules`

Comment: @bytefire - I have given the edit 2 section where I did start with a different way.. It would be really helpful if you have a look at it...

Comment: Kernel 2.6 is quite old. Is it the latest kernel that this hardware is compatible with? Also, according to http://www.domaigne.com/blog/computing/fixdep-failure-when-cross-compiling-the-linux-kernel/, it might be worth supplying CPATH which points to usr/include corresponding to that target. If you share the link where you downloaded the source from, that will also help.

Comment: Ya, the kernel is old but I have the limitation of not upgrading it. I downloaded the source code for Linux-2.6.8.1 from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/ and the tp-link wifi module from http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN725N.html#Driver , choosing OS for Linux (kernel 2.6.18 ~ 3.19.3). I have installed the headers following the link - http://man.chinaunix.net/linux/lfs/LFS_BOOK_6.0/chapter05/kernel-headers.html and making a folder tool/kheaders under top source directory.

Comment: @bytefire - After much introspection I got to know that **fixdep** is a ARM binary which I am running on my x86 system but I have no idea about how to tackle with this. 

Just to give you an idea of what I have already done, I had initiated by **make_mrproper** and then **cp arch/arm/configs/versatile_defconfig .config** and then proceeding with **make menuconfig** to modularize the new module I added to the Kconfig from top level source directory for linux-2.6.8.1 then **make ARCH=... CROSS_COM=......**

Comment: To compile kernel module, you don't need to play with kernel config. All you need is `ARCH`, `CROSS_COMPILE`, `M` and something to point to kernel source you are compiling against - in this case `KSRC`. So it's best to start with a command like following and then fix any errors that it throws: `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-uclibc- KSRC=<path to root directory for 2.6 _source_ you downloaded> M=<path to TP link driver root directory> modules`. It doesn't matter if driver source is in different path from kernel source.

Comment: Just noticed, for some reason the TP Link driver installation guide suggests running the make command as root. That shouldn't be required for compile to succeed. So it might also be trying to install the modules which you don't need.

Comment: @bytefire - Sorry for being a pain but I just wanted to say that I am already running the make as root. Also just wanted to ask that is it necessary for me to first compile the downloaded source kernel through simple **make** and then after successful build go for the cross-compilation? Just worried about the fixdep error that I am struggling with !

Comment: You don't need to compile kernel in order to compile the driver. For fixdep it might be worth looking into its source code to figure out where the error is coming from. Also, you don't need to be root in order to compile a kernel module, so I am not sure why it needs to be root.

Comment: @bytefire - May be just one last question. Which header files it is using during make presently? Where would I find headers for kernel-2.6.8.1 and how to link them for current cross-compilation?

Comment: If you point KSRC to root of the Linux source code you downloaded, that should be enough.